# Python pandas: creating condensed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
name      time       value1      value2
apple    8:30           17       21
apple    8:35           49       -24 
oranges  8:30           25       -31
orange   8:40           1         3
```

I want to create a dataframe that looks like this

```
name     8:30-value1   8:30-value2    8:35-value1    8:35-value2      8:40-value1     8:40-value2    
apple      17              21           49            -24              0               0
oranges    25              -31            0             0               1                3
```

I am new to pandas, how can I do this? The names of the columns of the resulting DF could vary, I just want it of that format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is slightly different output than you wanted, but I think you will like its form.  instead of finding the permutations of times with value1,value2 it uses hierarchical columns...

```
df = df.pivot(index='name',columns='time') 
#df = df.fillna(0) #to replace NaN with 0 as in your output example
```

**output**

```
         value1              value2
time       8:30  8:35  8:40    8:30  8:35  8:40
name
apple        17    49   NaN      21   -24   NaN
orange      NaN   NaN     1     NaN   NaN     3
oranges      25   NaN   NaN     -31   NaN   NaN
```

**edit - you can also use stack for same result**

The following is basically what the pivot method does in case someone needs to do something similiar but more complicated like even more hierarchical columns.

```
df.set_index(['name','time']).unstack('time')
```

Comment: I think if you use name `oranges` in place of `orange` and you use `fillna(0)` you should get almost expected result.

Comment: no Problem only reason there are orange and oranges is because they are different in his example.  Always can do some data cleaning with df.replace I guess.  You could probably use unstack to solve this as well